# rescheduling rooms

Tags: php

why is it still getting rooms with cancelled status?
can somebody please help me? what should be the right syntax for this?

```
$que=mysql_query("SELECT * from roomreservation where roomtype='$roomtype' and name='$name' and status != 'cancelled' and  

arrival > '$arrival' and arrival < '$departure' and
or
departure >'$arrival' and  departure <'$departure' and
or
'$arrival'  > arrival and '$arrival' < departure and
or
'$departure' > arrival and '$departure' < departure and
or
'$arrival' = arrival and '$departure' = departure and
or
'$arrival' = arrival or '$departure' = departure and


");

$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($que);
if($num_rows >0)
    {   $error="Room Already Reserved <br/>Please Choose another date";
        header("location:rescheduleroom.php?    id=$id&type=$roomtype&roomnumber=$name&error=$error");
            }
```

Comment: You need to group the statements. It's mixing the AND and OR clauses.

Comment: Please don't bother to tell us what those fields are, what do they contain, what those variables are, what type, we understand everything.

Comment: Query is invalid. You are using and or adjacently. Will that works?

Comment: besides query terminating with `and`!  `var_dump($que);` check if it's valid.

Comment: Can you please give us a little more background. What is going wrong? What do you expect to happen? What have you tried to do to fix it? Also, if you use correct grammar (capitalize the first word in a sentence at least), you'll probably be more likely to get help.

Comment: `and or`? how is this valid sql?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
 SELECT * from roomreservation where  
   roomtype='$roomtype' and name='$name' and status != 'cancelled' and  
( arrival > '$arrival' and arrival < '$departure' )  
or  
(departure >'$arrival' and  departure <'$departure')  
or
('$arrival'  > arrival and '$arrival' < departure )
or
('$departure' > arrival and '$departure' < departure )
or
('$arrival' = arrival and '$departure' = departure )
or '$arrival' = arrival or '$departure' = departure
```

NOTE: this is still a mess - but it's *closer*.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is highly overcomplicated. It can be boiled down to just this:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE roomtype='$roomtype' and name='$name' and status != 'cancelled'
   and ('$departure' >= arrival) and ('$arrival' <= departure)
```

Essentially, you've got the following. A room that's available/unavailable, and a series of options for how the potential arrival/departure dates overlap that availability

```
room:      ........XXXXXXXXX.......   <--- . = available, X = in use
         1    A  D
         2       A    D
         3           A    D
         4              A      D
         5                    A   D
```

cases 1 and 5 are obviously available - the A/D timepoints do not overlap the room's unavailability. 2,3,4 are the big ones, where they partially/completely overlap the blackout period. But if you look closely, in all cases that need to be considered, `A` is BEFORE the end of the blackout, and `D` is AFTER the start of the blackout, so your huge ugly and/or chain is just

```
   ('$arrival' <= departure) AND ('$departure' >= arrival)
```